# Getting tensors' name from restored checkpoint file: returns only one variable name

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have two question about restoring network with checkpoint files. 
I use [this code](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/) to restore my network. I only need to some part of my original network. actually, my original network consists with 5 convolution (very small) nets, all of these are connected to a big last fully connected layer. I only want have my 5 mini convnets. 
I define names for every single variable and every layer in my network. (I notice that when I run tensorboard with log data, everything is ok. that means, I have the names of all my variable and tensors appropriately)

1- my first  problem is when I want to find any of these variables by name in restored network, I face with "there is no tensor with this name" error. I also test my checkpoint file with [inspect_checkpoint.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py) and in output it returns only one variable:

```
Variable (DT_INT32) []
```

and in the other way, I tested it again with this code:

```
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
checkpoint_path = os.path.join('./', 'model.ckpt-100')
reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(checkpoint_path)
var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
for key in var_to_shape_map:
    print("tensor_name: ", key)
    print(reader.get_tensor(key))
```

and it returns:

```
tensor_name:  Variable
101
```

I cannot find the reason of this problem. Has anybody here have ever face with this problem?

2- Based on above site that I used to restore my network, I am a little bit confused. actually, I want to restore my all 5 mini convnet (all of these mini nets have a fully connected in their last layer). so, I really don't know what is the right way to restore every single mini convnet from its last fully connected layer with all its weights.

Comment: Unless you have an unusual use case for machine learning, I would really recommend that you give https://keras.io/ a go. It is a high-level machine learning library that sits on top of either TensorFlow or Theano, and makes building Deep Learning mode *much* quicker. 
pip install keras

Answer (score 0):

1- From the look of it, seems that you have not named your variables. It is not saving the variables names.
If that's the case could be that they work in training if you have different types, but then the writing to memory get messed up and overwritten when you try to build a dictionary with the same key name.

2- To fully restore your network you have to use

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(session_to_save, 'namefile')
...
saver.restore(session_to_restore, 'namefile')
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I put my code about every mini convnet into a python class and then for creating each of them I make a instance from that class. after defining that class, all of my variables' name in my project disappeared (based on my above description). I don't know why this is happened.